# 2 Dimensional Diffusion Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am solving a problem related to 2 dimensional diffusion equation and have a question about a detail.

With $$u_t-u_{xx}-u_{yy} = 0, \; t > 0, $$ I calculated that \begin{multline}\partial t\frac{1}{2}\iint_{R^{2}}u(t,x,y)^{2}dxdy = \iint_{R^{2}}u u_tdxdy=\int_{R}(uu_x|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{R}u_x^{2}dx)dy\\+\int_{R}(uu_y|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{R}u_y^{2}dy)dx,\end{multline} and I know $uu_x|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ and $uu_y|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ should both be zero. Assume this integral is well-defined and $\lim_{|(x,y)|\to\infty} u = 0$, but why $u_x$ and $u_y$ would not be large enough to affect the result, mathematically and physically?

Comment: Why is it clear that $\lim_{\|X\|\to\infty} u(X) = 0$? Isn't the same reason why $u_x$, $u_y$ are well behaved? Please elaborate, and maybe in the process you'll be able to answer yourself.

Comment: @Pragabhava Sorry about that. I think this is assumed to make the integral well-defined.

Comment: If it's _only assumed_, then why shouldn't you _assume_ the same thing for $u_x$ and $u_y$? Notice that, if differentiability is asumed, $u_x$ and $u_y$ also satisfy the heat equation (with different b.c.'s of course). As far as I recall, for the infinite plane problem, we construct the solution using the Fourier transform and then we prove absolute convergence for it and its derivatives. In fact, the solution is analytic.

Comment: So a better way to look at this is that $\int_U u \Delta u dx = -\int_U |\nabla u|^2 + \int_{\partial U} u \nabla u \cdot n dS$ where I think of $x$ as the whole coordinate vector and $dS$ is the surface measure on $\partial U$. Anyway, for this bound to do us any good when handling the whole space, we had better have that $\nabla u$, in addition to $u$ itself, is square integrable. In this case it should be possible to show that $\int_{\partial B(0,R)} u \nabla u \cdot n dS$ will go to zero as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: Of course with the heat equation we frequently cheat: we move time forward a little bit to make our function do all the nice things that we could ever like and then do our estimates with that as our initial condition, then move back to the original starting time and see what persists.